# Posting to cyclic and it's asking for package.json to be in the root?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

package.json not found at root level of repository.
Cyclic runs scripts defined "scripts" section to build, test and run your app.

But my project is set up like:

-final
--backend
---package.json(including npm start)
--frontend
---package.json(including npm start)
-package.json
^ includes:

```
"scripts": {
    "frontend": "cd frontend; npm start",
    "backend": "cd backend; npm start"
```

How do I merge these packages together and put them into the root directory so I can make this react application live?

I was thinking about something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "frontend": "cd frontend; npm start",
    "backend": "cd backend; npm start"
```

but when I go to the root directory (final)
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

Answer (score 0):

If you use yarn you could do something like `yarn --cwd frontend start`